# Django management commands inside App Engine Flexible environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I need a way of running remote commands inside my default service running on app engine flexible environment. The only way I can see (outside of connecting directly to the database) of running migrate is setting the instance to debug, ssh into the instance, attach to the docker container and then finally fun the management command.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not just run migrate locally, connecting directly to the database?

Comment: @jarmod how is this being done .. Been struggling for a while and I am stuck

Comment: I was assuming that the database could be reached from the developer's laptop so maybe he could simply run a copy of the Django app locally on the laptop, configured to talk to the real database, and then run manage.py migrate.